# boost multiple client connections

Tags: c++, sockets, boost

I'm trying to connect to multiple servers at once using the cpp boost library.
I wrote a Socket class, but for some reason, when i have multiple instances of one class, and try to connect, the other instance will connect aswell.

socket.h

```
class Socket{
private:
    boost::asio::io_service io_service_;

#if USE_SSL
    boost::asio::ssl::context context;
    boost::asio::ssl::stream<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket> ssocket;
#else
    tcp::socket ssocket;
#endif

    int headerLength;
public:
    Socket(int = HEADERLENGTH);

    bool connect(std::string, std::string);
};
```

socket.cpp

```
#if USE_SSL
Socket::Socket(int h) : context(boost::asio::ssl::context::sslv23), ssocket(io_service_, context){
    headerLength = h;
}
#else
Socket::Socket(int h) : ssocket(io_service_){
    headerLength = h;
}
#endif

bool Socket::connect(std::string host, std::string port){
    tcp::resolver resolver(io_service_);
    tcp::resolver::query query(tcp::v4(), host.c_str(), port.c_str());
    tcp::resolver::iterator iterator;

    std::cout << "resolving " << host << "\n";
    try {
        iterator = resolver.resolve(query);
    }
    catch (...){
        return false;
    }
    //ssocket.lowest_layer().set_option(tcp::no_delay(true));
    std::cout << "connecting to " << host << "\n";
    boost::system::error_code ec;
#if USE_SSL
    try {
        boost::asio::connect(ssocket.lowest_layer(), iterator, ec);
        if (ec){ // throw error
            return false;
        }
    }
    catch (...){
        return false;
    }
    //ssocket.set_verify_mode(boost::asio::ssl::verify_peer | boost::asio::ssl::verify_fail_if_no_peer_cert);
    ssocket.set_verify_mode(boost::asio::ssl::context::verify_none);

    ssocket.handshake(boost::asio::ssl::stream<tcp::socket>::client);
    std::cout << "connected \n";
    return true;
#else
    boost::asio::connect(ssocket, iterator, ec);
    return !ec;
#endif
}
```

I feel like it's having to do something with the way the constructor is called, but afaik are neither context nor ssocket static variables, or am I wrong?
USE_SSL is 1.
I would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is at the way you are using your Socket class. Here is a simplified version of your code, showing it works fine on a synchronous approach:

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/ssl.hpp>
#include <iostream>

class SecureSocket{
private:
    boost::asio::io_service io_service_;
    boost::asio::ssl::context context;
    boost::asio::ssl::stream<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket> ssocket;

public:

    SecureSocket():
        context(boost::asio::ssl::context::sslv23),
        ssocket(io_service_, context)
    {
        context.set_verify_mode(boost::asio::ssl::context::verify_none);
    }

    void connect(std::string host, std::string port){
        boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver resolver(io_service_);
        boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::query query( boost::asio::ip::tcp::v4(), host.c_str(), port.c_str() );
        boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::iterator iterator;

        std::cout << "resolving " << host << "\n";
        iterator = resolver.resolve(query);

        std::cout << "connecting to " << host << "\n";
        boost::asio::connect(ssocket.lowest_layer(), iterator);

        ssocket.handshake(boost::asio::ssl::stream<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket>::client);

        std::cout << "connected \n";
    }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    SecureSocket s, s2;

    try{
        s.connect("echo.websocket.org","https");
        std::cout << "---------\n";
        s2.connect("stackoverflow.com","https");

    }catch(std::exception& e){
        std::cout << "Error: " << e.what();
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Maybe you are calling each instance on its own thread and that is messing things up. Show us that part of the code, please.